# Could not deserialize class 'Functional'

Tags: python, django, tensorflow, keras, vgg-net

I did transfer learning to VGG16 model in order to classify images to cat or dog and here is portion of the code snippet:

```
prediction_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
prediction_batch = prediction_layer(feature_batch_average)

def manual_preprocess_input(x, data_format=None):

if data_format is None:
    data_format = tf.keras.backend.image_data_format()

  if data_format == 'channels_first':
    # If channels are first, move them to the last dimension
    x = tf.transpose(x, perm=[0, 2, 3, 1])

  # Mean subtraction (ImageNet means in BGR order)
  mean = [103.939, 116.779, 123.68]
  x = x - tf.constant(mean, dtype=x.dtype)

  # Zero-centering by subtracting 127.5
  x = x / 127.5

  return x
    
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(224, 224, 3))
x = data_augmentation(inputs)
x = manual_preprocess_input(
    x
)
x = base_model(x, training=False)
x = global_average_layer(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)
outputs = prediction_layer(x)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
```

And here is the view code where I loaded my model:

```
def testSkinCancer(request):

    model = tf.keras.models.load_model(
        os.getcwd()+r'\media\my_model.keras', safe_mode=False)

    print(">>> model loaded")

    if not request.FILES:
        return HttpResponseBadRequest(json.dumps({'error': 'No image uploaded'}))

    # Access the uploaded image directly
    uploaded_image = request.FILES['image']
    username = request.POST['username']
    user = User.objects.get(username=username)
    # Save the image to the database
    image_model = SkinImage.objects.create(user=user, image=uploaded_image)

    img_path = r'images/{0}'.format(uploaded_image)

    img = keras.utils.load_img(img_path, target_size=(224, 224))

    x = keras.utils.img_to_array(img)

    x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)

    predictions = model.predict(x)
    # You can perform additional processing here (e.g., resize, convert format)

    # Optionally, return a response to the client
    response_data = {'message': 'Image uploaded successfully'}
    return JsonResponse(response_data)
```

Then I saved it using `model.save('my_model.keras')`, then I loaded in a Django view but the problem is whenever I load it and make post request to the view, in the line where I load the model I encounter this error:

```
TypeError: Could not deserialize class 'Functional' because its parent module keras.src.models.functional cannot be imported.
```

What is the problem and how to resolve it?

Comment: Where exactly? Please update your question to include the full error trace (as text, not screenshot) - see how to create a [mre].

Comment: Does the error message not explain the problem? "because its parent module keras.src.models.functional cannot be imported"